# Get trace of executed Instructions in Spike simulator

Tags: assembly, profiling, trace, riscv, spike-simulator

Please provide various methods to generate a trace of executed instructions for C code using the [Spike simulator](https://github.com/riscv-software-src/riscv-isa-sim).

I have created a simple "Hello World" C file and generated hello.elf and then tried running this command:

```
/home/vindhya/riscv-vector/riscv-isa-sim/build/spike -l /home/latitude-7390/rvv64/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/pk hello.elf
```

The output obtained after running the "Hello World" C program on a RISC-V architecture seems unusual. Instead of the expected simple output, the program execution shows a repetitive sequence of RISC-V instructions involving memory loading and branching.

where could have gone wrong and how to fix the error?

Comment: If you're simulating a dynamically-linked Linux executable, there's lots of startup overhead with resolving library symbols and initializing library data structures (like stdio buffers and a malloc arena).  It takes a long time to get to `main`, and then inside `printf` or `puts` there's also lots of code, especially if your compiler doesn't optimize printf to puts so it has to process it as a format string.

Comment: nothing simple about a printf it is about as complicated as possible of a program/function call there is in C.  You are simulating a full operating system?  You have built the binary to match that operating system?

Comment: if you want a simple program and you are watching the instruction execution.  Then count from 0 to n in a loop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you implemented the print of "Hello World" and how the program was compiled. Judging from the use of proxy kernel (`pk`), it's very likely that you have *statically* linked your program against a standard C library (e.g. `newlib`). And the initialization of a C library does involve non-trivial sequence of instructions. You can verify this by `objdump -d` your ELF program, and check the assembly.